# Why It’s difficult to remember which props or state are used by functions outside of the effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As part of learning React hooks I was going thru their official doc. But When I read one statement I got stuck. The statement is like this

> It’s difficult to remember which props or state are used by functions
> outside of the effect.

But I could not understand it fully. I mean why it is difficult to remember which props or state used by function outside the `useEffect` ?. Is it because of the  `closure` in JavaScript? If so , can some one elaborate it?.

Below is an example they provided in the doc.

```
function Example({ someProp }) {
  function doSomething() {
    console.log(someProp);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    doSomething();
  }, []); //  This is not safe (it calls `doSomething` which uses `someProp`)
}
```

If the problem is to remember all the dependent values then how would it solve using the below mentioned code. The doc says

> It’s difficult to remember which props or state are used by functions
> outside of the effect. This is why usually you’ll want to declare
> functions needed by an effect inside of it. Then it’s easy to see what
> values from the component scope that effect depends on

```
function Example({ someProp }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function doSomething() {
      console.log(someProp);
    }

    doSomething();
  }, [someProp]); // ✅ OK (our effect only uses `someProp`)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In complicated components, the functions can be long. If `doSomething` was actually 30 lines long, not just one line long, and it called *other* functions itself too, then to figure out all possible values the call of `doSomething` depends on, you would have to go trace through all those functions.

In even a medium-sized project with decently sized components, simply trying to *remember* what all values are required by each function call could well be a challenge, even for someone who knows the language well. It gets much worse if the code needs to be understood by someone who *didn't* write it.

This is why there are linting rules such as [`exhaustive-deps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) which will automatically prompt you to add all such dependent values to the dependency array - both reducing the requirement to remember the dependent values, and reducing the possibility of bugs (if you leave out a dependent value in a dependency array, it's *probably* either a bug or an indication of faulty component structure - but not always).

Comment: So , what my understanding is that when the function is big with many dependencies then it would be difficult to remember all those dependent values to put in the dependent array of useEffect method.  But what if we defined the big function inside the useEffect method itself , still we need to remember the dependencies right?. Please see my EDIT. So what is the difference between the two code snipets?

Comment: Yes, whether the function is defined inside or outside the effect callback, it'd be a good idea to list all its dependent values in the dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

They're talking about human frailty. :-) In a couple of ways.

There's the long function problem:

```
function Example({ someProp }) {

    function doSomething() {
        console.log(someProp);
    }

    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
  
    useEffect(() => {
        doSomething();
    }, []); //  This is not safe (it calls `doSomething` which uses `someProp`)
}
```

And there's the maintenance-over-time problem — suppose originally the code was:

```
function Example({ prop1, prop2 }) {

    function doSomething() {
        console.log(prop1);
    }

    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
  
    useEffect(() => {
        doSomething();
    }, [prop1]); // This is fine
}
```

then you or someone else on the team, weeks or months later, has to change the code a bit and adds to `doSomething`:

```
function Example({ prop1, prop2 }) {

    function doSomething() {
        console.log(prop1);
        console.log(prop2);
    }

    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
    // some code here
  
    useEffect(() => {
        doSomething();
    }, [prop1]); //  This is not safe (it calls `doSomething` which uses `prop2`)
}
```

You can mitigate that with processes, such as the one that they mention — a build tool that analyzes dependencies and calls out missing ones.